# Python 3 web page to lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

im trying to read from a web using python 3, and then printing all the lines one by one.

the best way i saw so far is using urllib.request and do somthing like this:

```
import urllib.request
url_target = urllib.request.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com")
tmp_copy_string = url_target.read().decode("utf8")
file = "file"
for word in tmp_copy_string:
        print(word)
```

i thought this code print word by word - it dosnt....

the problem is not only it dosnt print word by word, but char by char...

is there a good way to print line by line?

without using additional libraries.

Comment: My 2 cents => Suggest using httplib2 over urllib. You will find it to be comprehensive which may avoid code refactoring later. Check out @ https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it by `\n`:

```
import urllib.request

url_target = urllib.request.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com")
tmp_copy_string = url_target.read().decode("utf8").split('\n')    #split string on newline

for line in tmp_copy_string:
        print(line)
```

This will print the code line by line

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library when trying to make requests to urls. Its easy to use and well documented. You can install it via `pip install requests`.

Now if you want to split text by new lines, you can do `.split('\n')`, but this situation is so common that we have another function for that [`.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). Here is a session without decoding the text, so the text is in unicode:

```
>>> import requests
>>> var = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
>>> lines = var.text.splitlines()
>>> lines_iter = iter(lines)
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'<!DOCTYPE html>'
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'<html>'
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'<head>'
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'    '
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'    <title>Stack Overflow</title>'
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830">'
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=fd7230a85918">'
>>> next(lines_iter)
u'    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch
```

You don't need to use `iter`, `splitlines` returns a list, and you can iterate over that using a `for` loop. But I've used `iter` here to demonstrate.